# Which is more conductive?

Tags: acid-base, conductivity

There are two choices. One is Nitric acid, and the other is phosphoric acid.

The solution of each type of these acids has a concentration of 0.1 mole. I answer would be phosphoric acid, because each molecule contains more than 1 hydrogen ion. Thus it would be more conductive.

Does strong/ weak affect conductivity?

Answer (score 2):

Whether the acid is a strong or weak acid does affect its conductivity.  Weaker acids are less dissociated and generate fewer ions in the equilibrium.

Nitric acid $\ce{K_{a}=24}$

Phosphoric acid $\ce{K_{a}=7.1 x 10^{-3}}$

[link to Ka reference](http://depts.washington.edu/eooptic/links/acidstrength.html)

Nitric acid is more dissociated than phosphoric acid

**Electrical Conductivity κ in mS/cm at 1 Mass Percent Concentration**

[link to conductivity reference](http://sites.chem.colostate.edu/diverdi/all_courses/CRC%20reference%20data/electrical%20conductivity%20of%20aqueous%20solutions.pdf)

Nitric acid ~ 56.1

Phosphoric acid ~ 10.1

Nitric acid is more dissociated and more conductive than phosphoric acid.

Comment: Do u memorize these things, which is dissociated more? And the constant of ionization for each acid?

Comment: But then in one mole of phosphoric acid, there are are three moles of hydrogen ions? Which is significantly more than what sulfuric acids have.

Comment: "Do u memorize these things" - No way, just google them; "one mole of phosphoric acid, there are are three moles of hydrogen ions" - Doesn't really matter if it doesn't ionize (dissociate) very much.

Comment: Why but more ions means a stable current of electricity?

Comment: Understood, but there are not more ions with phosphoric acid because it doesn't dissociate.  Above I gave the value for the first ionization constant for phosphoric acid and it was 10^-3 times smaller than the dissociation constant for nitric acid.  Look at how much SMALLER the second and third dissociation constants are for phosphoric acid;.  There is just a LOT LESS H+ present with phosphoric acid compared to nitric acid(https://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/sstutorial/Text12/Tx125/tx125.html)